# Filter json data by boolean value in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to filter json-data in cell by boolean values

Everything just fine when I filtering just by numeric values:

```
select id, 
       jsonb_path_query(terminals->'terminal', 
                        '$ ? (@.maxLength >= $length)', 
                        '{"length": 1.0}') as terminals 
FROM public.table;
```

And when I'm trying to filter by boolean value:

```
select id, 
       jsonb_path_query(terminals->'terminal', 
                        '$ ? (@.boolValue == TRUE && @.maxLength >= $length)', 
                        '{"length": 1.0}') as terminals 
FROM public.table;
```

I get it:

```
ERROR:  syntax error, unexpected IDENT_P at or near " " of jsonpath input
LINE 1:  jsonb_path_query(terminals->'terminal', '$ ? (@.boolValue...
                                                 ^
SQL state: 42601
```

Comment: I just needed to write TRUE in lowercase 
```select id, jsonb_path_query(terminals->'terminal', '$ ? (@.boolValue == TRUE && @.maxLength >= $length)', '{"length": 1.0}') as terminals FROM public.table;```